# How to get xfce4-volumed to work in Lubuntu?

Tags: notification, lubuntu, xfce, volume-control, lxde

I want to use `xfce4-volumed` in Lubuntu, because I like the volume notification popup that it gives when changing the volume in Xubuntu. Lubuntu still lacks this feature.

Simply installing `xfce4-volumed` in Synaptic Package Manager doesn't seem to work: running `xfce4-volumed` in a terminal won't show me the expected popup when changing the volume. The terminal doesn't look like it's actually running anything: it immediately gives me a new prompt (yourname@ubuntu:~$) instead of showing some sort of debug log.

I've tried to install `xfce4-mixer` as well. This program does run, but it still won't give me the `xfce4-volumed`-popup when changing the volume, even in combination with `xfce4-volumed`.

How can I get `xfce4-volumed` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need some prerequisite packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-volumed gstreamer0.10-alsa
```

`xfce4-volumed` is a daemon that requires the gstreamer-alsa plugin to work.  Normally you would have this run on startup.

However, for testing I just ran `xfce4-volumed` from a `lxterminal`.

If you then use the standard volume control you'll see the popups - you'll also need to clear the notification envelope in the system tray to see further popups.

[image]

In testing though - I found that xfce4-volumed was quite temperamental - sometimes it stopped working and the only way to get it to start again was to logout and login :(

Comment: Thanks for answering my question again, fossfreedom :-). However, it doesn't seem to work here. This might have something to do with pulseaudio being installed and set as a startup application.

Comment: curious - I've just done a `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`, reboot, `start-pulseaudio-x11` and the instructions above - still works... how did you do the install and config?

Comment: I looked somewhat further. It turned out that `notification daemon` was not checked in my startup programs. I've got it checked again right now, and everything works. Again,  thanks for your help, fossfreedom.

Comment: For future readers: if you want to keep having the volume popups, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166194/how-can-i-make-xfce4-volumed-keep-giving-notifications-in-lubuntu