# How can I make xfce4-volumed keep giving notifications in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, notification, volume-control

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04, with `xfce4-volumed` installed, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74230/how-to-get-xfce4-volumed-to-work-in-lubuntu). When I'm changing the volume using <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Vol-</kbd>, a nice notification balloon pops up. This is what I want. However, when I try to change the volume 10 seconds later, I first have to click the 'Clear all notifications' button to get further notifications. I want to get rid of this: `xfce4-volumed` should always be giving notifications, whether or not I've clicked the button.

How can I get this done?

Answers that tell me how to disable the whole envelope thing, or change it by another notification daemon to get this done, are also welcome.

[image: This is what I want to happen: the balloon indicating the volume as I change it]
[image: This is what annoys me: I first have to click the button to get further notifications]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by installing the XFCE-popups. You can read about how to make it work [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/88648).

The only difference between those instructions and "ours" is that we no longer have notify-osd in Lubuntu 12.04. It has been replaced by the notification-daemon. There are two ways you can get rid of the compatibility issues:

1. `sudo apt-get remove notification-daemon`
2. delete the notification-daemon autostart file from `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.

Reboot. Enjoy.

Comment: Works. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

http://xfce.10915.n7.nabble.com/XFCE-volume-manager-daemon-disabling-notifications-td9405.html

Why don't you remove notification area from your panel?

Right click on panel.

Click on "Properties".

Click on "Add new items".

Click on "Notification area" icon.

Click on "Delete".

Simple.